# iBooks pre-loading of pages interferes with animation

Tags: ibooks

My ebook does animations driven by `setTimeout`. (I am using `requestAnimationFrame` when available, which it's not on older iPads running iOS 5). The book is composed of about 100 separate XHTML files to ensure page breaks occur exactly where they should, which is otherwise an iffy proposition in iBooks.

Immediately after opening the book, animations are **very** slow (eg one second per step, rather than 50ms), but after keeping the book open a while (a minute or so?), the animations ran at expected speed.

The reason I found: iBooks is apparently pre-loading all the pages in the book (I suppose in order to get page numbers, or speed up page turning). The pre-loading seems to be interfering with my animations--stealing `setTimeout` slots, as it were.

I had thought the problem might be the time required at load time to set up the animations on each document, but timed those and found it was just a few milliseconds per page. The problem may be a semi-large script (100K) on each of the 100+ pages, which I imagine iBooks is parsing over and over again as it preloads each page.

I have considered the option of including the large script dynamically when each page is viewed, but got stuck on figuring out how to tell when that is. We have no PageVisibility API in Safari, and the `focus` event does not fire on initial page load, so how do I tell when the page is actually being viewed, as opposed to stealthily pre-loaded in the background by iBooks?

My next attempt is going to be to shrink the number of individual XHTML pages down to 1 or a few, and take my chances with `page-break-*` and its ilk to handle page breaking.

What I need is a way to (1) tell iBooks either to **not pre-load other pages in the book** or  (2) **give my `setTimeout` requests priority** over those queued up by iBooks for preloading pages or (3) know when a page is being displayed so I can inject the script at that point in time.

See also [epub 3, how to prevent pages from running in background ? (iBooks / Readium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706725/epub-3-how-to-prevent-pages-from-running-in-background-ibooks-readium) and [FInding out when page is being viewed in EPUB FXL via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483574/finding-out-when-page-is-being-viewed-in-epub-fxl-via-javascript).